# Need optimized sql advice

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

So i have this database full of tables like suppliers, clients, stores, store_users, services(of each store), repairs, etc etc (a database of a IT brand that repairs computers at each store).

In the "repairs" table i have fields regarding the client, hardware, breakdown, condition and state of the repair("started", "waiting for client answer", "delivered" and others).

Everytime there are changes in the repair, for example: user1 received the repair order and  inserted the repair into the system. user2 tested harddisk, RAM, etc for problems, found major disk problem so it needs to be replaced.

This information will change many fields in the "repair" but i need something like another table "interventions" to know what changed and who did what in each time there was an edit to the repair.

The only idea i had was to make a new table "interventions" with all the fields from the "repairs" table and every time someone edited the repair it would copy it to the intervention with a id_repair and a id_user linked.

PS: Users are the store's employees

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606031/generic-version-control-strategy-for-select-table-data-within-a-heavily-normaliz/606100#606100

Comment: @daftdev Sounds like you need to set up some triggers

Comment: @JensSchauder yes, it helped but didn't provide me a clear answer or aproach

Comment: @SelectDistinct what do you mean by set up some triggers?

Comment: @DaftDev You said everytime there is an update/insert/delete etc from the 'repairs' table you would like an audit trail within a new table called 'interventions'? I thought you could create a trigger on the 'repairs' table that added a new row in the 'interventions' table everytime a change occured detailing the users and timestamp etc, or am I getting the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: @SelectDistinct that's what my initial idea was. I was just asking if there is a easier/more efficient way to save the "history" of a repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your "repair" table needs to be renamed to "interventions" and what you currently see as the "repair" table changed to a view which shows the most recent intervention.

Comment: that seems a lot more efficient and easy to query. Thanks!